# passive event listener, fullpage.js, Callbacks

Tags: javascript

I connected onepage.js and when I click on navifation I get an error[Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnrxo.jpg)

<

```js
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    autoScrolling:true,
    scrollHorizontally: true,
    navigation: true,
    sectionSelector: '.page-section',
  });
```

Comment: The error is due to the [mishandled passive option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Improving_scrolling_performance_with_passive_listeners)  in `addEventListener`, but as it occurs in a library, what do you expect us to do for you?

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: @GRANDMASTER Please update your snippet so it reproduces your problem.

Comment: You can save the library on your own server, and make the fix to the code. We can't say, how exactly to do this without seeing the developement version of library code. Generally speaking, you've to find the `addEventListener` line attaching the event firing the error, and add `{passive: false}` to the arguments. You could also contact the author of the library, and report a bug, maybe they'll fix it.

Comment: I don't have such a line addEventListener in fullpage.js